# How do I get the systems caret period in .NET?

Tags: .net, wpf, caret

How do I know the exact period of the caret blinking on a certain Windows system? (Programmatically using .NET)

Comment: What is a caret in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can P/Invoke it.

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getcaretblinktime

Answer (score 3):

You can always simply P/Invoke [`GetCaretBlinkTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Daniel's answer gives the copy/pastable signature).

If you don't mind having a reference to Windows Forms, there is also [`SystemInformation.CaretBlinkTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.caretblinktime.aspx). Unfortunately it seems that the analogous [`SystemParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.aspx) class does not expose this setting.